# Downgrade iOS SDK from 5.1 to 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

I've been developing an app, which is ready to be sent to verification at Apple.
I've been beta testing 5.1, so both my Xcode and iPhone is configured with SDK 5.1 and so is my app.

Apple do not accept apps with 5.1 right now, so is there an easy way to downgrade the SDK to 5.0? I've tried editing the value of "Base SDK" but only 5.1 shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll have uninstall Xcode and iOS SDK an reinstall 5.0 downloaded from apple.

you can use this command:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just download and install XCode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 separately in a different location on your mac as well.